# How to include a collection inside an array in php?

Tags: php

I have an empty array like the below,

```
$sample = [];
```

I need to add collections inside the empty array like the below.

```
$sample = [
{
'item1' : 12,
'item2' : 15,
'item3' : 18,
'item4' : 17
},
{
'item1' : 10,
'item2' : 25,
'item3' : 8,
'item4' : 7
}
];
```

How could I  do that?

Comment: I want a collection inside an empty array . Could you please help me ?

Comment: Collection - meaning you want to use it later in JS?

Comment: No, I want it in PHP.

Comment: You can make two array and push these two array in initial array.                                 
 <?php 

$sample = [];

$array1=[

'item1' => 12,
'item2' => 15,
'item3' => 18,
'item4' => 17
];
$array2=[
'item1' =>10,
'item2' => 25,
'item3' => 8,
'item4' => 7
];
array_push($sample,$array1);
array_push($sample,$array2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sample);
echo "</pre>";


?>